# ASP.net Web Server Control, children are NOT maintenaing state

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am developing a custom server control, following is control's markup on my ASPX page,

```
<uc:NoteBook ID="nb1" runat="server">
    <NotePages>
        <uc:NotePage ID="p1" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </uc:NotePage>
    </NotePages>
</uc:NoteBook>
```

Note that this control has `NotePages` property which is actually a collection of `NotePage` control. And `NotePage` control can have any type of children.

On the same aspx page, in `Page_Load` event handler, I am loading some items in `DropDownList` control,

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    this.ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Class-1", "C1"));
    this.ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Class-2", "C2"));
    this.ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Class-3", "C3"));
}
```

**Problem:**

Now problem is after Post Back, the `DropDownList` items get cleared. Which is clearly indicating I am missing some state management here.

Can anyone please guide my how to handle it?

Following is the control code.

```
public class NoteBook : CompositeControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public virtual List<NotePage> NotePages
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public NoteBook()
    {
        this.NotePages = new List<NotePage>();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        foreach (var c in this.NotePages)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(c);
        }
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}

[ParseChildren(false)]
public class NotePage : UserControl
{

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the items when initializing the control not during the load event.  Note: that the items need to always be added, not just when the page is not loading during a GET.  By the time the load event has occurred the state has been initialized.  See `[Control Execution Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28VS.71%29.aspx)'

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken, are you talking about the DropDownList items? If yes then I don't think we should add items each time (either GET/POST), whats the point of ViewState then?

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it.

We just need to call the `EnsureChildControls()` method on control initialization, which causes child controls to be created before the ViewState/etc. things gets called.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.EnsureChildControls();
}
```

I added above code in my `NoteBook` control.